# Shorten polylines a given distance

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, editing, line, polyline-creation

I have a polyline dataset with lines of different lengths. I want to shorten all polylines the same distance on both ends (e.g. 10m each side). Is there a tool or script available that could help me do this? I want to automate this process, so manual editing is no option.

I´m using ArcGIS 10.0 with an ArcView license.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use this simple steps as arcpy script, or as Model:

- use the [tool Feature vertices to points](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000003p000000) with `BOTH_ENDS` option.
- Buffer the resulted points with 10m.
- Erase the lines using the buffer result.

in the case of Arcview i have found this [erase script](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=14625) , or this [question about using erase in arcview](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22826/cutting-features-in-arcgis-10)

Comment: Good idea. Unfortunately I only have a ArcView license. Both, "Feature vertices to points" as well as "Erase" require ArcInfo. I´m able to do the "Feature vertices to points" using a free ArcGIS extension, but I don´t know how to do the "Erase" without adequate license.

Comment: Thanks, the first script is outdated I think, but the second link was helpful