# Using R to subtract polygon area of one shapefile from another?

Tags: raster, r, polygon

I'm looking to produce a map from two separate maps in R. My Maps files are as follows:

ftp://ftp.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/GIS/us_tempprcpfcst/610prcp_20140822.zip #Map1
ftp://ftp.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/GIS/us_tempprcpfcst/610prcp_20140812.zip #Map2

These are 6-10 day weather Precip maps from NOAA.

I would like to create a map with the area showing, being only the difference of the two maps. So `Map1 - Map2 = Map3`.   Also, I would like it to show the relative strength of the change for the above or below normal moisture. Which can be seen in the "Prob,N,13,11" & "Cat,C,254" files of the dbf file.

Without success I have tried: 
converting to PolySet and then using `joinPolys` with the Operation="DIFF". 
Also:
using `readOGR`, checking for gIsValid, and then trying to use `gDifference`.

When I run the second one I get this error:

> Error in RGEOSBinTopoFunc(spgeom1, spgeom2, byid, id, drop_not_poly, "rgeos_difference"): 
>   TopologyException: no outgoing dirEdge found at -168.86604844949545 63.300706978948405

I am sorry if it seems like such a simple question of taking the difference between two maps but I have been stuck on this question for a number of days now.

Comment: This may help: http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/109639/8104