# Erase polygon from line to get line using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, line, erase

How can I erase a polygon from a line to get the erased line?

Conceptual image below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your license level allows it, use the [Erase Tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Erase/00080000000m000000/).

If your license level will not allow it, you can find a workaround at [Performing reverse clip in ArcMap?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/82807/performing-a-reverse-clip-in-arcmap)