# Retain the rest of the Clip (Analysis) tool in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, clip, erase

Which tool can I use to get or keep the rest of the output feature when I use the Clip (Analysis) tool in ArcMap?

For instance I need to calculate Blue minus Green. 
[image]

Erase (Analysis) from Overlay will do. 
That's what I was looking for.

[image]

Comment: There's several [overlay tools](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/analyze/commonly-used-tools/overlay-analysis.htm) that will accomplish the job, though you may need to use attributes to select out the pieces in one that are not in the other.

Comment: Since these are polygon layers and you are only wanting to process two layers you can use the Union tool with all license levels. You would query for features that had Null values in the Green FID field.  If you have an Advanced license you can use the Erase tool create a new feature class that has removed all of the Green areas from the Blue area.  Identity does basically the same thing as Union for two polygon layers, but it requires an Advanced license..

Comment: Duplicate of this http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/103746/how-to-create-a-feature-class-from-the-area-in-one-layer-not-covered-by-another   and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22826/cutting-features-to-do-opposite-of-clipping-in-arcgis-desktop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you need the [Erase](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Erase/00080000000m000000/) tool, in the Analysis toolbox > Overlay toolset. [Here's](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000800000009000000.htm) a good link showing all the overlay tools. It depends on the license you have though. If you don't have the appropriate license you can do an intersect (which will keep everything), then you can select by location those features in your intersect layer that intersect Green, and delete those. Then you'll have the Blue left over.